# How to return an array from functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

How do I get the HTML array back in `.then(function(document){})`,

all code:

```
const phantom = require('phantom');
(async function() {
    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();

    const status = await page.open('https://lasgsfgdf.com/').then(function (status) {
        if(status == 'success') {
            page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.querySelectorAll('.resourceList > .resourceListItem');
            }).then(function(document){
                console.log(document[0].innerHTML);
            });
        }
    });

    await page.close();
    await instance.exit();
})();
```

Works only when the string is returned.

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('.resourceList > .resourceListItem')[0].innerHTML;
}).then(function(document){
    console.log(document);
});
```

I need so that I can process the array, already in `then`, since in `.evaluate(function() {` работает только `return`, no idea why so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You can try wrapping your async function in a promise then using `resolve (document[0].innerHTML);` to resolve it

Comment: Something like this?
`
https://pastebin.com/NbAvu7D2
`